# Raspberry Pi Reverse Proxy Performance

Tags: performance, pi-1

I currently have a Nextcloud server on a Raspberry Pi 3, which works perfectly fine. In addition I want to setup my Raspberry 2 as a Gitlab Server.

I also have an unused Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+, which I could use as an reverse proxy with nginx + Let's Encrypt SSL management and GeoIP Blocking. So Pi2 and Pi3 need not care about about that which could be a huge performance advantage.

But the question is: Does the slow performance of the Pi1 have any impact on the performance of the other two Pi's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it with uploading a single 300MB file to nextcloud (no encryption enabled):

- Upload Speed with Pi 1 as reverse proxy: **3-4 MB/s**
- Upload Speed with Pi 2 as reverse proxy: **9-10 MB/s**
- Upload Speed with no reverse proxy (direct access to Pi 3): **~12MB/s** (nearly full 100MBit/s)

So the Pi 1 as reverse proxy have an impact on the network speed. For example the speed of generating thumbnails does not have an impact, because it's happening on the Pi 3.